# With the following code I still get a horizontal scroll bar

Tags: iframe, scrollbar

I have the following code but am still getting a horizontal scroll bar.  How do I turn it off?

```html
 <style>
        #IDXSearchBox {
            width:900px;
            height: 7500px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            overflow-x: hidden;}
 </style>

 <iframe 
      id=IDXSearchBox 
      src="http://mrmlsmatrix.com/Matrix/public/IDX.aspx?idx=########">
 </iframe>
```

I have also tried adding `scroll-x:hidden;` to the CSS but it had no effect.

Thanks,

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have written there works when i shrink the height and width of the iframe. The horizontal scroll bar your seeing is probably for the entire page because the iframe is so wide, rather than a scroll bar for the iframe itself.

 More likely is that its your browser, since overflow-x and -y are new to CSS3, try it on the newest version of Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: I think your correct.  I'm working with a WordPress template that is narrower than the 900px.  The template must be adding the scroll bar.  Most likely my problem lies there.  NOTE: the 900px is what is called for by the source applet.

Comment: Try adding the overflow-x: hidden in the content div in wordpress, like the entire blogging column, or maybe just the div containing the iframe.